# Remove match word using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to split and join two type of url. For example 
**Url 1 :** 
`http://localhost/site/index.php?route=product/category&path=20&sort=p.price&order=ASC&order=DESC`
**Url 2 :** 
`http://localhost/site/index.php?route=product/category&path=20&limit=8`

```
<input type="hidden" class="sort" value="http://localhost/site/index.php?route=product/category&path=20&sort=p.price&order=ASC&order=DESC" />

<input type="hidden" class="limit" value="http://localhost/site/index.php?route=product/category&path=20&limit=8" />
```

I'd like to join the query strings but remove duplicates.

I'm looking for this result at last

```
http://localhost/site/index.php?route=product/category&path=20&sort=p.price&order=ASC&order=DESC&limit=8
```

Comment: [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript) should give you what you need to split the GET parameters. then, all you have to do is aggregate them in a dictionary and rebuild the URL off that dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could go with getting the query parameters in an array and [de-duplicating](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9229821) them.

```js
var url1 = "http://localhost/site/index.php?route=product/category&path=20&sort=p.price&order=ASC&order=DESC";
var url2 = "http://localhost/site/index.php?route=product/category&path=20&limit=8";
var url  = (url1.split`?`[1]+"&"+url2.split`?`[1]);
var result = url1.split`?`[0]+"?"+Array.from(new Set(url.split`&`)).join`&`;
console.log(result)
```

Note that you're left with `order=ASC` and `order=DESC`, of which only the last is processed. But looks like that's what you want...

For older browsers:

```js
var url1 = "http://localhost/site/index.php?route=product/category&path=20&sort=p.price&order=ASC&order=DESC";
var url2 = "http://localhost/site/index.php?route=product/category&path=20&limit=8";
var url  = (url1.split('?')[1]+"&"+url2.split('?')[1]);
var result = url1.split('?')[0]+"?"+url.split('&').filter(function(x,i){
  return url.split('&').indexOf(x) == i;
}).join('&');
console.log(result)
```

Comment: @MAHAR So you don't want this way? **Why** don't you want this way?

Comment: The problem is on my site script because i want to dynamically add this using ajax  when i add this my whole site's javascript function stop working  .  But `atulquest93` answer working. So need other easy and short way like your answer.

Comment: @MAHAR Do you use `url` variable elsewhere?

Comment: @MAHAR Added a snippet for older browsers.

Answer (score 1):

```
var getUrlParameter = function getUrlParameter(sParam, url) {
    var sPageURL = decodeURIComponent(url),
        sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&'),
        sParameterName,
        i;

    for (i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
        sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');

        if (sParameterName[0] === sParam) {
            return sParameterName[1] === undefined ? true : sParameterName[1];
        }
    }
};
```

Now read individual parametrs by

```
var order = getUrlParameter('order', 'http://localhost/site/index.php?route=product/category&path=20&sort=p.price&order=ASC&order=DESC');
var limit = getUrlParameter('limit', 'http://localhost/site/index.php?route=product/category&path=20&limit=8');
```

and make a new url by using the parameters.

Comment: Hay working but i don't want to write `http://localhost/site/index.php?route=product/category` manually because i want to add this function dynamically.